# Oracle Warehouse Builder Design center can't start

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, oracle-warehouse-builder

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 64bit, I want to use warehouse builder which is included in it, but the problem is that I can't open Design center, it gives me the following error.

```
 application could not start correctly (0xc0000018)
```

could anyone help me with this, I can't find a solution

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/610495/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000018-windows-8-x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution to this problem, when you download oracle database 64bit, the warehouse builder is included with it, but the design center is working only with 32bit computers, i don't know why oracle would do that, so i downloaded oracle warehouse builder standalone, and configure it following the steps in the oracle official tutorial, and now it works prefectly.