# Oracle Design Center application could not properly error 0xc0000018

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, data-warehouse

Hi i installed oracle 11g R2 on Windows 10 64 bit desktop.
I have configured the listener and database correctly without any error.But when i launched Design Center it shows the following error please help.

```
application could not start correctly (0xc0000018)
```

Please help me find solution i even deleted the key from

> regedit

but it didn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Warehouse Builder Design center can't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713398/oracle-warehouse-builder-design-center-cant-start)

Comment: that question he answered and said i followed the following steps but he did not give any links

Comment: So? All Oracle software products are available on OTN's Download section.